# rsync vs. Finder performance transferring to SMB

Tags: rsync

The server is a recent Ubuntu running Unraid 6.10.2 and offering files using SMB.

The client is a macOS 12.5.1 and also with rsync 3.2.5. Mounting the disk as SMB using Finder.

A targeted task is copying a 100 GB .sparsebundle file (a lot of 8MB files).

When attempting this copy using Finder we see sustained 7 MB upload performance.

But when attempting using `rsync --recursive --times --delete` there is under 1 MB upload and the command will hard freeze before completing. No beach ball, just 100% unresponsive, cannot be COMMAND-OPTION-ESCAPED, and after a few minutes you can see the BIOS (EFI) login screen.

Ideally, rsync can be fixed as this will be useful for the SECOND backup which need only be incremental.

Is this combination of software incompatible and causing this problem?

Comment: Rsync is an unprivileged program. If you're seeing a hard reboot then there's a hardware fault or a kernel bug that's being triggered by rsync's actions.